# POST Route, generates MethodNotAllowedHttpException when calling GET

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have declared a POST ROUTE:

```
Route::post('sessions', [
'as' => 'sessions.store',
'uses' => 'UserAuthenticationController@store'
]);
```

When i access www.domainname.com/sessions it generates an MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

I`m trying to handle all missing routes using:

/ global.php /

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
return View::make('exceptions.404');
});
```

I cannot figure out why is generated this Exception while I have not declared any GET ROUTE for (sessions).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `debug = true` in your application

When you application debug is set to `false`, it will show the 404 page.

Comment: If I call another route not declared it sends me to 404 Page,
I don`t think it is going through that error because of DEBUG = true.

While I have not declared a GET Route it should get casted by APP::missing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem would be in your Controller

```
class UserAuthenticationController extends Controller
{

public function store()
{
return View::make('sessions.store');
}

}
```

just don't forget it only works when you post ; you can also use

```
Route::any('sessions', [
'as' => 'sessions.store',
'uses' => 'UserAuthenticationController@store'
]);
```

make sure in your view in the sessions folder the stroe file name correctly like

> store.blade.php